# Where can I get data for the popularity of a book?

Tags: data-request, books

I need to collect some data to find the popularity of books.

The first thing that came in my mind was to find the number of sales of the books, but I soon found that the authors don't easily tell their book's total sales so my data would be unreliable and hard to find.

Do you know where I can get reliable data for the popularity of books?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goodreads has an API: https://www.goodreads.com/api

and specifically the [Review Program](https://www.goodreads.com/about/review_program)

> **Review Syndication:** Goodreads has 10 million reviews across 700,000 titles - one of the largest and deepest collection of quality book reviews on the internet. Our API makes it easy to display these reviews on your website.

- [Reviews Widget](https://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_demo_widget_iframe?isbn=0142437174)
- [Reviews API method](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show_by_isbn) (must be whitelisted)

To get data on popularity you could find highly-rated books, or books with many total ratings.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a good method, but this method would be slightly biased as people are more likely to give 5 start and 1 star ratings. However, with that many members I think I would get a good idea of the overall popularity, thank you for your answer.